# Debug Mysql Connection

Tags: mysql

I have a process, in mysql database, with localhost user. But I want to discover the origin of this connection (What is the IP Adress).

```
ID: 46504
Host: Localhost
Command: Sleep
Time(Sec): 10.000 
Info: (NULL)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start the mysqld (MySQL daemon) with **--log or -l** switch. See [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) for details. If you left --log alone without a filename it defaults the filename to **host-name.log** (where host-name is your computer name).

Comment: OK, but I am monitoring in real time with MONyog. And, the hostname is localhost. Thanks!

Comment: Go find a file named my.cnf (for Linux) or my.ini (for Windows). Inside this file uncomment the line which says **general_log_file** and **general_log** and restart the mysql daemon. Do search this file for entries that you need once you connect to your database.